# How could I wrap an area of a string with an html element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I had something like the following:

$400/week

$800/week

With jQuery being available, what would be an ideal method of wrapping the "/week" part in an html element like `<span class='small'>/week</span>`?

Comment: Is the string within another element, show us more of the markup ?

Comment: `var str = str.split('/')[0] + '<span class='small'>/' + str.split('/')[1] + '</span>';`

Comment: @TomasVoracek - It's usually done for different styles etc.

Comment: @adeneo You are right. Didn't realize that! Sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
var data = $("#text").html();
$("#text").html(data.replace(/\/\s*week/g, '<span class="small">/week</span>'));
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/TKa8D/

Note: Replacing HTML will undo any event handlers assigned within that HTML so you should generally replace the HTML at the lowest level possible so you aren't replacing elements that already have event handlers on them.  If you share your specific HTML, we could make more concrete recommendations for the easiest way.

Comment: What if you already have event handlers attached to some of the other elements in the element containing the text?

Comment: @icktoofay - that depends upon the HTML layout.  First choice would be to zero in on a particular element's text that wouldn't interfere with event handlers.  Second choice would involving manually walking each text node to find just the text that you could modify.  Without the OP sharing that all that extra work is required, this is the easier first solution.

Answer (score 1):

It's not pretty, but the only safe way to do it (preserving event handlers and such) is to walk the tree, splitting text nodes where necessary. Unfortunately, jQuery does not like working with text nodes; it is very element-centric.

You can start by defining a helper function to do the recursion:

```
function recurse(node, fn) {
    if(node.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE) {
        fn(node);
    }else if(node.nodeType === Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
        var children = Array.prototype.slice.call(node.childNodes);
        for(var i = 0, l = children.length; i < l; i++) {
            recurse(children[i], fn);
        }
    }
}
```

It walks every node in the tree, calling a given function for every text node. Then we can use that function to split the text nodes and insert a `span` in the middle:

```
recurse(document.documentElement, function(node) {
    var re = /(\$\d+)(\/week)/;
    var match;
    while(match = re.exec(node.nodeValue)) {
        var before = document.createTextNode(node.nodeValue.substring(0, match.index + match[1].length));
        node.parentNode.insertBefore(before, node);
        var span = document.createElement('span');
        span.className = 'week';
        span.textContent = node.nodeValue.substring(match.index + match[1].length, match.index + match[0].length);
        node.parentNode.insertBefore(span, node);
        node.nodeValue = node.nodeValue.substring(match.index + match[0].length);
    }
});
```

**[Try it.](http://jsfiddle.net/uDg6V/)**

Comment: Please consider IE 7 and maybe 8 not knowing the Node constructor and so throwing a ReferenceError when trying to get Node.TEXT_NODE or Node.ELEMENT_NODE. To stay cross browser you will have to use their final integer values which are respectively 3 and 1.

Comment: Moreover, jQuery is able to work with other than element nodes. Instead of using children method, you can use contents method.